# Swift 4: NSPredicate from UITextField and array of custom object

Tags: ios, swift, nspredicate

I have an array of custom object.

```
class MyObject {
    var code: String!
    var name: String!
}
```

I want to `autocomplete` a `textField` for that I have a `tableView` that I display when the user start writing. I have to filter my array datasource depending on the `textField.text`. For that I added a selector to the `textField`, then I test if there are names of elements in the array containing the `textFiled.text` using `NSPredicate`.

This is the textField selector:

```
    @objc func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
            if (textField.text?.count != 0 && textField.text != " ") {
                let resultPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "ANY name CONTAINS[c] %@", self.countryTextField.text!)
                print("resultPredicate \(resultPredicate)")
//self.allDatasource type is [MyObject]
                self.filtredDatasource = self.allDatasource.filter({
                    return resultPredicate.evaluate(with: $0.name)
                })
            } else {
                self.filtredDatasource = self.allDatasource
            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
```

When I start writing a name the application crash due to this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSCFString 0x6040004215e0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key name.'
```

So the problem is in `NSPredicate format`. I searched about this issu and I found that I can use `ANY` then put the field name that I want to check.

Am I wrong? How can I solve this problem?

Note: I'm using Swift 4

Comment: `resultPredicate.evaluate(with: $0.name)` => `resultPredicate.evaluate(with: $0)`. Your predicate is built to evaluate a `MyObject` object.. But writing `$0.name`, it's then evaluating the property `name` (a `String`) of a `MyObject` object which is translated by your error message, because he then try to find a `name` property on a `String`. But I'd remove the `ANY` too.

Comment: @Larme I want to compare `MyObject.name` with the `textField.text` . This is why I put $0.name

Comment: That’s not what says your predicate. Did you try my solution at least?

Comment: @Larme This is what I have understand from your comment: `NSPredicate(format: "name CONTAINS[c] %@", self.countryTextField.text!)`  `self.countriesDatasource = self.allCountries.filter({
                return resultPredicate.evaluate(with: $0)
            })` I test it and the app is crashing  `NSForwarding: warning: object 0x60400028f2d0 of class 'myApp.MyObj' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead
Unrecognized selector -[myApp.MyObjj valueForKey:]`

Comment: Missing @obc before var name I guess

Comment: @Larme you're right! I was missing the "@objc" before var name. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think for this to properly work, you need to make your object available to the Objective-C side:

```
class MyObject: NSObject {
    init(code: String, name: String) {
        self.code = code
        self.name = name
    }

    var code: String
    @objc var name: String
}
```

The predicate is evaluated over the object you give it. In your case, you provide it a `String`. For the predicate to check that, you should use `self`:

```
let resultPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "self contains[cd] %@", searchText)

let filtered = allDatasource.filter {
    resultPredicate.evaluate(with: $0.name)
}
```

You can also give it a *MyObject* to evaluate, then you can use the name of the property:

```
let resultPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "name contains[cd] %@", searchText)

let filtered = allDatasource.filter {
    resultPredicate.evaluate(with: $0)
}
```

In your code, you use the `ANY` modifier. That's a modifier you can use to check if there is *any* item in a collection that adheres to the predicate:

```
let searchText = "n2"
let resultPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "ANY name contains[cd] %@", searchText)

let allDatasource = [ MyObject(code: "c1", name: "n1"), MyObject(code: "c2", name: "n2")]
let containsAnyObject = resultPredicate.evaluate(with: allDatasource)

// true for 'n2'
```

Comment: Thank you it work! @Sh_Khan solution also is working but I accept your because of the good explanation!

Comment: I wonder if you can explain what's the utility of the @objc at this level

Comment: You need `@objc` to expose types, properties and functions you declare in Swift to the Objective-C runtime. A topic to big for a comment :) https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

Comment: You are amazing! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try filtering like this

```
let searchText =  self.countryTextField.text

self.filtredDatasource = self.allDatasource.filter { ($0.name as! String).range(of: searchText!, options: [.diacriticInsensitive, .caseInsensitive]) != nil }
```

Comment: This is what I get `Cannot convert value of type 'String?' to expected argument type 'String.Element' (aka 'Character')` in the last line